Xperience password reset for Banno
We have created the external ap via Banno and the Xperience has been configured but we are receiving and error. enter image description here
Created Xperience password reset option in Banno and when trying to test we receive an error code.

Unfortunately, there's not enough information in the question to understand where things may be going awry. Can you add more info on the specific API call you're making (with redacted values where necessary)? Also, if you could get an x-request-id from the API response header, that'll help narrow things down too.

Some things to look at include the Troubleshooting page, Reset a User Password guide, Building User Support Tools guide, and the API Reference for the Admin API's Password Reset endpoints.
